# The content copied from a richtextbox is not getting saved in my database

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Am trying to copy the content of a Richtextbox to another Richtextbox using the below code.

```
FlowDocument doc = RTB1.Document;
RTB1.Document = new FlowDocument();
RTB2.Document = doc;
```

But the copied line disappears if i try to save the screen where the RichTextBox(RTB2) is there.

Any help on this will be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying the content from one RichTextBox to another the content used to disappear because the focus was not coming back to the copied RichTextBox.

So the solution i used was to set the focus of RichTextBox2 after copying.

```
 FlowDocument doc = RTB1.Document; 
 RTB1.Document = new FlowDocument(); 
 RTB2.Document = doc; 

 RTB2.Focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `RTB1.Document = new FlowDocument();` will asign a new FlowDocument value to the RTB1.that's why the copied line disappears.

Try this
 first you need to include the namespace and add the code below

```
        using System.IO;
        using System.Windows.Markup;


       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

       XamlWriter.Save(RTB1.Document, ms);

       ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

       RTB2.Document = XamlReader.Load(ms) as FlowDocument;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the code it copies all the lines to my 2nd RichTextBox but as soon as i click save button on my application those lines disapper.

Comment: can u please specify the code that you mention in save button.

Comment: Save is done by a BaseData class which i dont have access to and have no idea how it works. I just have to pass the dataset and database connection string to the save method. My dataset has all the column names of the table and my RichtextBox corresponds to one of the columns. When i type something in it that will be automatically updated to the dataset. But when am copying it from another RichTextBox my dataset is not get updated with the copied text.